# Query BigQuery table partitioned by Day on a timestamp field

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table partitioned by Day on a timestamp field as below:

[image: Table details]

Data Sample:

```
Row _time                    dummy_column
1   2020-06-15 23:57:00 UTC  a
2   2020-06-15 23:58:00 UTC  b
3   2020-06-15 23:59:00 UTC  c
4   2020-06-16 00:00:00 UTC  d
5   2020-06-16 00:00:01 UTC  e
6   2020-06-16 00:00:02 UTC  f
```

Due to the fact that the table is partitioned on `_time` but it is partition by Day, so in order to query in a specific day partition `2020-06-15`, I run:

```
select * from {DATASET}.{TABLE} where _time >= TIMESTAMP("2020-06-15") and _time < TIMESTAMP("2020-06-16");
```

Result:

```
Row _time                    dummy_column
1   2020-06-15 23:57:00 UTC  a
2   2020-06-15 23:58:00 UTC  b
3   2020-06-15 23:59:00 UTC  c
```

My question is: Is there a way to query a Day partition directly by mentioning the it explicitly instead of querying using a timestamp range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a table partitioned by Day, you can directly reference the partition day you want to query.

In order to demonstrate your case, I have used the following table schema:

```
Field name      Type    Mode      Policy tags   Description
date_formatted  DATE    NULLABLE    
fullvisitorId   STRING  NULLABLE
```

Other table's details,

```
Table type              Partitioned
Partitioned by          Day
Partitioned on field    date_formatted
Partition filter        Not required
```

And some sample data,

```
Row date_formatted  fullvisitorId
1   2016-12-30  6449885916997461186
2   2016-12-30  3401232735815769402
3   2016-12-30  2100622457042859506
4   2016-12-30  4434434796889840043
5   2016-12-31  9382207991125014696
6   2017-12-30  4226029488400478200
7   2017-12-31  4304624161918005939
8   2017-12-31  4239590118714521081
9   2018-12-30  0030006068136142781
10  2018-12-30  7849866399135936504
```

You can use the syntax below to query the above sample data,

```
DECLARE dt DATE DEFAULT Date(2016,12,30);

SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table_name` WHERE date_formatted = dt
```

The output,

```
Row date_formatted  fullvisitorId
1   2016-12-30  6449885916997461186
2   2016-12-30  3401232735815769402
3   2016-12-30  2100622457042859506
4   2016-12-30  4434434796889840043
```

As you can see it only retrieved the data for the specific date I declared.

Notice that I have used the [DECLARE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#declare) clause because it facilitates modifying the date filter. Also, if your field is formatted as a TIMESTAMP, you can replace [DATE()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date) to [TIMESTAMP()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp) to define your filter within your variable.

*As an additional information, if you want to use a range, consider using the BETWEEN clause such as `WHERE partition_field BETWEEN date_1 and date_2`.*

**UPDATE:**

I have used your sample data this time, I have used the below syntax to create a table exactly like you described. Below is the code:

```
create table dataset.table_name(_time timestamp, dummy_column string) partition by date(_time) 
as select  timestamp '2020-06-15 23:57:00 UTC' as _time, "a" as dummy_column  union all
select  timestamp '2020-06-15 23:58:00 UTC' as _time, "b" as dummy_column  union all
select  timestamp '2020-06-15 23:59:00 UTC' as _time, "c" as dummy_column  union all
select  timestamp '2020-06-16 00:00:00 UTC' as _time, "d" as dummy_column  union all
select  timestamp '2020-06-16 00:00:01 UTC' as _time, "e" as dummy_column  union all
select  timestamp '2020-06-16 00:00:02 UTC' as _time, "f" as dummy_column
```

The table:

[image]

The schema:

[image]

The details:

[image]

In order to select only one date from your timestamp field (_time), you can do as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table` WHERE DATE(_time) = "2020-06-15"
```

And the output,

[image]

As it is shown above the output is as you desired.

*Moreover, as an extra information I would like to encourage you to have a look at this documentation about [partition by](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#partition_expression).*

Comment: Thanks @Alexandre, but your answer agrees with the query I have mentioned in my question regardless the BETWEEN clause. Yes, my partition field is timestamp, and I want to query one Day partition, so my question is that if there is a way to query that on full day single partition instead of querying with a timestamp range?

Comment: @YasserMohsen, you can do as it is in my query, declare the timestamp you want and write it in your where clause with a "=" sign. The query I posted above it returns only the results from the day 2016/12/30. I have updated the answer with an output.

Comment: first of all, forget about the "Declare" clause, there is no difference if I used it or not, it is just to make the query prettier. Regarding to using the day directly like your query, it is not valid in my case as I have timestamps not days. Please have a look on the data sample in my question.

Comment: Thanks. The last query is exactly what I want. Please consider upvoting my question if it much clearer now.

Comment: @YasserMohsen, I have upvoted the question. I am glad I could help.